# MVC 3: Where can I find default templates for DisplayForModel and EditorForModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

Where can I find the default templates for DisplayForModel and EditorForModel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the default templates here:

ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures / http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
    bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata) {
        return metadata.ShowForDisplay
            && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
            && !metadata.IsComplexType
            && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
    }
</script>
<% if (Model == null) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText %>
<% } else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
<% } else { %>
    <% foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm))) { %>
        <% if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) { %>
            <%= Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) %>
        <% } else { %>
            <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.GetDisplayName())) { %>
                <div class="display-label"><%= prop.GetDisplayName() %></div>
            <% } %>
            <div class="display-field"><%= Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) %></div>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if/where you can see the defaults without looking at the source code but you can create your own in the following directories to override the defaults:

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml`

and

`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Object.cshtml`

Does this help?

Here's a great post on Brad Wilson's blog that will walk you through how to create your own default editor and display templates: [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 4: Custom Object Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html)

Comment: This does not help. I want to perform a minor change on the default (source) template, therefore I want to have a look at it.

Comment: See the link that I added to my answer. You're going to have to create your own in order to make any changes at all. The post covers the default layout and how to make changes.

Comment: On your edit: I would rather suggest http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html but as you see, that is MVC 2. And I know that I have to create my own, but in order to create my own I want to see how the default template looks. As I said, I only want to make a minor change.

Comment: Found the templates here - http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781 - but I can't make my own answer.

Comment: The default template rendering is done in code. There is no view file. If you really want to see the code get the MVC source and look at TemplateHelpers.cs

Comment: You are partly wrong. If you clicked my link, you would notice a download link which is named ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures. When you've downloaded the zip, you would notice that there is a file named Object.ascx, which is the corresponding template for DisplayForModel().